# What does it mean that boundary terms vanish in Partial Differential Equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

While reading Haberman's Applied Partial Differential Equations, the topic on self-adjointness, what does it mean that "boundary terms vanish"?

More context:

"Supposed that `u` and `v` are any two functions, but with the restriction that the boundary terms happen to vanish":

$p(u\displaystyle\frac{dv}{dx} - v\displaystyle\frac{du}{dx})\Big|_a^b \ = 0$

Comment: "A function vanishes at $x$" just means that $f(x) = 0$. In your case, the boundary conditions vanish because they equal zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"vanish" just means it evaluates to zero, i.e.

$$ u(a) = u(b) = 0 $$
$$ v(a) = v(v) = 0 $$